# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text_channels'

Tags: python

```py
import discord
import random
client = discord.Client()
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self,user))
    async def on_message(self,message):
        guild = client.get_guild(server id)
        mymsg=input("type your message")
        await random.choice(guild.text_channels).send(mymsg)  
client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```

When ever I run this I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text_channels'`
I have tried to change some code and yet it shows the error So i very much need help

Comment: check why `guild = client.get_guild(server id)` return None. This is the actual problem

Comment: Does this code even compile (run without syntax error)? I don't remember that identifiers (`server id`) can have spaces in it.

Comment: I have put a real server id there...